# Cannot find protocol declarations in project-swift.h

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-bluetooth

I am trying to build my project but am getting these errors:

> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CBCentralManagerDelegate'; did you mean 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'?```
>
> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CBPeripheralDelegate'```

on this code in my `Project-Swift.h` file

```
@class CBService;
@class CBCharacteristic;

@interface KestrelDeviceConnect (SWIFT_EXTENSION(FieldView)) <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
```

Anyone know what the issue is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

seems like I needed to enter this line of code in the `Project-Bridging-Header.h`

`#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>`